# What is meant by (I come from)?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is meant by **(I come from)** in the following sentence:

- **I come from Canada, but my parents are Chinese.**

Does it mean that the speaker (was born in Canada), or that (he has the Canadian nationality), or it simply means that (he arrived from Canada)?

Answer (score 1):

### "Come from" means your origin.

By itself,

> I come from Canada.

typically means only #1 or #2:

> - **Yes:**  1. I was born in Canada.
> - **Yes:**  2. I am a Canadian citizen.
> - *No:*  3. I am arriving from Canada.

With the context that "my parents are Chinese", the first part of the sentence should have the same idea -- **national origin** (nationality) or citizenship.

### Why not #3?

It is an **idiom** that "(a person) comes from (a place)" typically refers to their place of origin.

For other meanings, such as **immediate arrival**, you might hear a different form of the verb "to come":

> - She **is coming** all the way from the city, so she'll probably be late for dinner.
>
> --- [*The Free Dictionary*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+from#Definition)
>
> - I **am coming** from Halifax.
> - I **am coming** from work.
> - A letter **is coming** from the judge.
> - A letter **came** from the killer.
> - That toy **came from** the toy store.

You will generally not hear:

> - *No:* I come from work.

Work is not the place where you live, or your origin.

> - *No:* I am from Japan, but I come from Halifax.

If you mean you are **arriving** from Halifax, the "-ing" verb means something that is **happening right now**, so this is correct:

> - **Yes:** I am from Japan, but I **am coming** from London to attend the conference.
> - **Yes:**  I am from Japan, but I **am arriving** from London.

### Exceptions

In English, you can often create an exception.

Here is a very rare case where you might say "I come from work".

Remember, this is not ok:

> *No:*
>
> Alice: This is a great party! Where were you before this?
>
> Bob:  I come from work.

(It should be "I came from work.")

If it is a **regular occurrence**, then where you were immediately before might be thought of as your origin.

> **Yes:**
>
> Alice: Why are you always late to our **regular appointment, every Wednesday**?
>
> Bob:  I come from work, and the traffic is terrible.